# I don't understand anything on this ad

Tags: discussion, advertising

I just see this ad recently (first time I see it):

[image: IMB ad]

I find five problems with it:

1. Red circles: there is two french verbs, one is infinitiv ("créer" <=> "to create") and the other is ("Accédez" <=> "Go")...well it's hard to explain it in english so I'll just say that it appears in different form, not infinitiv and I find this strange to change that specific form, **it's not homogeneous**. I'll change that to "Accéder".
2. Purple circle: I just don't get it. Please french people, explain to me what it's supposed to tell me about the situation. I don't know what are the words in the english version of the ad, maybe it's more clear.
3. Blue circle: it's not really a problem and more a question. I know for long that the "===" is mostly used in Javascript (I actually don't know another language that use it), so was it used on purpose on this ad? Is this ad used to promote "something" that I can code in Javascript and only Javascript?
4. I decided to click on the ad to check where it brings me. A single page promoting "IBM Cloud" and some button to login, register or access to doc/support/prices. The thing is: the ad speak about Chat Bot and it appeal me, so where it is ? (but maybe I just don't know much things on ad on Stack Overflow and maybe it's just normal)
5. Last thing that bothered me, it's about the "créer" word again: it's very uncommon, even when we code in french, to use **accent** in variable names.

So, to my point of view, it's not a good ad (even though I clicked on it...)

Comment: Add to that that `//` is a single line comment in every language I know that uses it. Line 2 should either start with `//`, or not have comment highlighting. Guess this ad is made by a PR person without consulting a dev. However, it's a non-SO ad. As long as SO gets paid and it's not offensive, it's not really our problem.

Comment: I fail to see what you expect SO to do about this.

Comment: Get to 200 reputation, then you wont see these ads anymore

Comment: *I find five problems with it*. That is too bad. Had you found 6 to 8 problems you would be eligible for a prize...

Comment: The question is not about the SE ad engine, it is about this specific SO ad. Thus, it is ontopic, the close reason is not okay.

Comment: Hi, I'm french. I can't help with 2. Must be a direct translation of "Innovation in [field]!".

Comment: Yeah it means 'innovating in the customer relationship"... Which is weird.  As for the verb tenses, they aren't supposed to be the same. The grammar is correct that way.

Comment: PSA: there are no problems with red circles.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wouldn't read too much into what the ad is trying to say; it's just an ad. Some artistic license is expected.

The wording and, more importantly, the fact that you're not satisfied with what you saw after clicking the link might be real problems to the folks who are paying to run the ad.

You need to take that up with IBM, though. There's probably nothing Stack Overflow can do about it; they're presumably just running with what IBM gave them.

Comment: You're right! I "forget" that it's not really SO who decides what kind of ads are displayed. My bad on this "question", thanks (you and other comments) for your clarifications. :)

Comment: Wasn't there something about SO only wanting to show relevant/high quality ads? (I can't find the post/blog unfortunatly)

Comment: @AndréKool That's what I thought too, but I probably don't explain nor focus on this in my question. But it's probably too difficult or not interesting for SO to work that much on this.

Comment: [Here is the link](https://stackoverflow.blog/2016/11/15/how-we-make-money-at-stack-overflow-2016-edition/) (You have to scroll down a bit to Stack Overflow Ads)